# Jquery erase text with type effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I write some script to add text with typing effect. I need to remove text like that effect but don't know how do that. If can please help.

JS Code :

```
var title = $(".form-title").attr("data-title");

$.each(title.split(''), function (i, letter) {
    setTimeout(function () {
         console.log(letter);
        $('.form-title').html($('.form-title').html() + letter);
    }, 500 * i);
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/ucvvegay/6/)

Comment: you see the example?

Comment: yes I know. I want after adding all letters, remove it like that effect, letter by letter from the end to begin

Comment: yes I know how to explain it on my language. I just know bad english sorrry

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89239/discussion-between-aram-mkrtchyan-and-zl3n).

Comment: if you haven't found the answer you can check [shabdawali](https://github.com/amitguptagwl/shabdawali) plugin

Answer (score 4):

```js
var title = $(".form-title").attr("data-title");
var interval = 200;
var wait = interval + (interval * title.length);

$.each(title.split(''), function (i, letter) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $('.form-title').html($('.form-title').html() + letter);
    }, interval * i);
});
var i = title.length;
while(i >= 0){
    setTimeout(function () {
        var text = $('.form-title').html();
        var length = text.length - 1;
        $('.form-title').html(text.substring(0, length));
    }, wait + (interval * i) );
    i--;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2 class="form-title" data-title="Dear Concept Studio,"></h2>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can trim the last letter of the HTML content with each iteration.

For example:

```
$('.form-title').html($('.form-title').html().substring(0, title.length-1-i));
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ecvbL0f7/2/

Answer (score 2):

use the following javascript. Check the demo also in the below

```js
var title = $(".form-title").attr("data-title");

$.each(title.split(''), function (i, letter) {
    setTimeout(function () {
     if(title.length-i!=1) {
        $('.form-title').html(title.substring(0,title.length-i));
          } else {
            $('.form-title').html(title.substring(0,title.length-i));
            setTimeout(function() {
              $('.form-title').html("");
              },500);
            }
    }, 500 * i);
  
});
$('.form-title').html("")
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2 class="form-title" data-title="Dear Concept Studio,"></h2>
```

Comment: There's an off-by-one error in your code. The first letter remains visible. See my answer.

Comment: @RickViscomi In your answer the last letter(,) disappears without the time interval(I  mean in the beginning of onload itself)

Answer (score 2):

If you already had the text:

```
<h2 class="form-title">Dear Concept Studio</h2>
```

Then you would remove it with this:

```
var H2 = $("h2");
var H2Length = H2.text().length;

$.each(H2.text().split(''), function (i, letter) {
    setTimeout(function () {
         console.log(H2.text().substring(0,H2Length-1));
        H2.text(H2.text().substring(0,H2Length-1));
        H2Length--;
    }, 500 * i);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

There you go, a snippet for you:

```
var 
    $title = $("h2");


var func = function() {

    $title.text($title.text().substring(0, $title.text().length - 1));

    if ($title.text().length > 0) {
        setTimeout(func, 100);
    };
};

func();


http://jsfiddle.net/ucvvegay/7/
```

on jsFiddle

Answer (score 2):

Try like this,

```
var title = $(".form-title").attr("data-title");
var leng = title.split('').length-1;
$.each(title.split(''), function (i, letter) {
setTimeout(function () {
    // console.log(letter);
    if(i===leng){deleting()}
    $('.form-title').html($('.form-title').html() + letter);
}, 500 * i);      

});
function deleting (){
var text = $('.form-title').html();    
var length = text.length-1;
$.each(text.split(''),function(i,letter){        
    setTimeout(function () {                        
    $('.form-title').html(text.substring(0,length-i));
},500*i);
});
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ucvvegay/9/

Answer (score 2):

This is JS code to animate **typing effect then erasing it and showing a blinking cursor**. You may further tweak the code.
credits goes to original author *Simon Shahriver*.

Here's the Fiddle: https://codepen.io/jerrygoyal/pen/vRPpGO

```js
var TxtType = function(el, toRotate, period) {
        this.toRotate = toRotate;
        this.el = el;
        this.loopNum = 0;
        this.period = parseInt(period, 10) || 2000;
        this.txt = '';
        this.tick();
        this.isDeleting = false;
    };

    TxtType.prototype.tick = function() {
     
        var i = this.loopNum % this.toRotate.length;
        var fullTxt = this.toRotate[i];

        if (this.isDeleting) {
        this.txt = fullTxt.substring(0, this.txt.length - 1);
        } else {
        this.txt = fullTxt.substring(0, this.txt.length + 1);
        }

        this.el.innerHTML = '<span class="wrap">'+this.txt+'</span>';

        var that = this;
        var delta = 200 - Math.random() * 100;

        if (this.isDeleting) { delta /= 2; }

        if (!this.isDeleting && this.txt === fullTxt) {
        delta = this.period;
        this.isDeleting = true;
        } else if (this.isDeleting && this.txt === '') {
        this.isDeleting = false;
        this.loopNum++;
        delta = 500;
        }

        setTimeout(function() {
        that.tick();
        }, delta);
    };

    window.onload = function() {
        var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('typewrite');
        for (var i=0; i<elements.length; i++) {
            var toRotate = elements[i].getAttribute('data-type');
            var period = elements[i].getAttribute('data-period');
            if (toRotate) {
              new TxtType(elements[i], JSON.parse(toRotate), period);
            }
        }
    };
```

```css
body {
  background-color:#ce6670;
  text-align: center;
  color:#fff;
  padding-top:50px;
}

* { color:#fff; text-decoration: none;}

.wrap{
   animation: caret 1s steps(1) infinite;
   border-right: 0.08em solid #fff;
  padding-right: 1px;
}
@keyframes caret {
  50% {
    border-color: transparent;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>
  <a href="" class="typewrite" data-period="2000" data-type='[ "Hi, I am Jerrygoyal.", "I am Creative.", "I Love Design.", "I Love to Develop." ]'>
    <span class="wrap"></span>
  </a>
</h1>
```